# How to replace exact matches from a list of strings with special characters python?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am removing all exact matches in my list_of_strings from a pandas dataframe column.  I don't really understand the re.escape that is being used, however.  I want to make sure this code will remove ALL matches no matter what type of character is present in my list_of_strings variable and in my dataframe column.  What does re.escape really do?  I've read the documentation but am newer to regex and would appreciate a more layman's terms explanation.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": [1, 2],
        "name": [
            "I have a %$$#form with @#$%$#%@/}\p special characters!!!!",
            "can we: remove the EXACT matches !#$#%$^%$&^(*&*)(*&)_&#",
        ],

    }
)


list_of_strings = ['can we: remove', 'with @#$%$#%@/}\p special characters!!!!','EXACT']


p = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, list_of_strings)))
df['cleaned_text'] = [p.sub(' ', text) for text in df['name']]
```

Answer (score 1):

In regex, some symbol have a meaning and trigger some functionality, when you want to explicitly match the symbol without triggering its function, you escape it.

Now re.escape is simply a method to avoid escaping a list of character manually.

instead of escaping (adding `\`) manually like  this :

> "\$\[\]\^"

You can simply do like the function you write.

> pattern = "|".join(map(re.escape, "[$[]^"))
>   "\$|\[|\]|\^"

To see what do your code, simply print p.

```py
list_of_strings = ['can we: remove', 'with @#$%$#%@/}\p special characters!!!!','EXACT']


p = '|'.join(map(re.escape, list_of_strings))
print(p)
```

As you will see all characters have been escaped `\`.

Comment: what is the difference between my code and what you put with all the special characters?  Is my code "explicitly" matching anything from my list of strings or do I need to specify what characters I want to escape?

Comment: @acodejdatam simply do that, you will se, but all your special character are not escaped. `print("|".join(map(re.escape, list_of_strings)))`

Comment: what do you mean? I get a syntax error when I run print(&#39;|&#39;.join(map(re.escape, list_of_strings)))

Comment: so this means that every character within my_list_of strings will be an exact match and replacement, because I am escaping the functionality if it had something to do with regex, right?  So my code above would remove only the special characters contained in my list_of_strings?

Comment: @acodejdatam Yes and no. It will for all special character, but as you escape letter as well this will have another meaning. \w match all non alphanumeric character.

Comment: Benard, all I am concerned about is removing the exact matches from my strings and in my text.  What does my code need to be for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop:

```
for i in list_of_strings:
    df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(i, '', regex=False)

print(df)

   ID                                   name
0   1                     I have a %$$#form 
1   2   the  matches !#$#%$^%$&^(*&*)(*&)_&#
```

---

Maybe there is an easier way:

```
df.name.str.replace(list_of_strings[0],'', regex=False)\
       .str.replace(list_of_strings[1],'', regex=False)\
       .str.replace(list_of_strings[2],'', regex=False)
```

Output:

```
0                       I have a %$$#form 
1     the  matches !#$#%$^%$&^(*&*)(*&)_&#
Name: name, dtype: object
```

Comment: the list of strings I have in my real world example is 4000 elements.  Need something that wouldn't have to be hard coded like that but I like the regex=False option.  Any ideas?